# How to download this file from Sharepoint by API?

Tags: file, url, sharepoint, download

I'm the following URL: https://companyName.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/Documentos compartidos/Adjuntos/PS00000650/7A80B90F-75A3-4162-BD19-0AD21ECAB4C6.pdf

and I need to download the file using an API.

I have tried to use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

But doesn't work for me

Any ideas? Is possible to download the file using API?

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

Comment: PD: Graph.microsoft doesn´t work for me, because I only have the URL, not the Folder ID or File ID

Answer (score 0):

You can use following api to get item by path

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path}
```